# how to get trac to run with apache?

Tags: apache, trac

i have some problems getting trac to be running with apache.

have no idea of how to do and the tutorial i followed doesnt work.

```
http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModPython
```

i have an empty /etc/apache2/httpd.conf. should it be empty?

then i followed the tutorial and typed in:

```
LoadModule python_module modules/mod_python.so
```

so now it contains one row. i have ubuntu and i installed mod_python with:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-python-doc
```

however, when i run a2enmod mod_python it says:

```
ERROR: Module mod_python does not exist!
```

but i have checked that it exists in /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_python.so.

so whats the problem?

Comment: Seems you are better off using [`mod_wsgi`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithTrac) now days over `mod_python`, not that the [documentation](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall#WebServer) got any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, installing mod_python via:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-python
```

will enable it.  If it does not, the correct command is:

```
a2enmod python
```

note, the module is 'python', not 'mod_python'.

Answer (score 0):

First, your httpd.conf may be empty, but you should also have a apache2.conf in the same directory that actually contains all the server directives.

As for the module, I was having the same issue and then did some digging.  If you look in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, you should have one in there called "python.load" (I do at least).  If you open that up with vi, you will notice the following line in that file:

```
LoadModule python_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_python.so
```

I think that it may just be that its installed with a different name.  If someone else knows different, I would be interested in hearing their views as well.

Regards,

Jeff

Comment: is the apache2.conf the main configuration file for apache or is it the httpd.conf?

Comment: yes i do have python.load in that folder. so what's next? how do i start trac when apache starts? and why does apache2 tell me: ERROR: Module mod_python does not exist!. when i type in: a2enmod mod_python

Comment: @never_had_a_name: The command has changed from "a2enmod mod_python" to just "a2enmod python".